# Change margin top of div based on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a bar at the top of my page that is position fixed. When the user scrolls to a certain point I want the bar to start moving up as if it was relatively or absolutely positioned.

Right now the css of the bar changes from fixed to absolutely positioned but of course this sets the div straight to the top of the page.

I have been looking at this for ages and cannot get my head around how I would push the bar up one pixel at a time for every pixel scrolled past the _triggerOffset

Can anyone enlighten me?

```
function banner(){

    var _barOffset = $('#top-bar').outerHeight(),
        _navOffset = $('#navigation').offset().top,
        _triggerOffset = _navOffset-_barOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (_scroll >= _triggerOffset) {
            $('#top-bar').css({'position':'absolute'});
        }

    });

}

banner();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a fiddle.

Check this fiddle

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/ej3Wx/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var postionToTriggerMove = 500;
  var positioninitial = $(window).scrollTop();
  var positioninitialLine = $(".line").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(_scroll > positioninitial) {        
       if(_scroll >= (postionToTriggerMove - 5) && _scroll <= (postionToTriggerMove + 5) )
          {
              var topBarPostion = $(".line").offset().top;
              $('.line').css({'position':'absolute',"top":topBarPostion});
          }
   }
   else {
       if(_scroll >= (postionToTriggerMove - 5) && _scroll <= (postionToTriggerMove + 5) )
          {
              var topBarPostion = $(".line").offset().top;
              $('.line').css({'position':'fixed',"top":positioninitialLine});
          }

  }
  positioninitial = _scroll;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below:

```
function banner(){

    var _barOffset = $('#top-bar').outerHeight(),
        _navOffset = $('#navigation').offset().top,
        _triggerOffset = _navOffset-_barOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (_scroll >= _triggerOffset) {
            $('#top-bar').css({'position':'absolute','top':_triggerOffset - (_scroll-_triggerOffset)});
        }

    });

}

banner();
```

This code is highly untested, however what we are doing is initially setting the element to an absolute position and defining the top of this element as the _triggerOffset, then we take the difference between the current scroll and the triggerOffset and subtract this from the top position to make the bar move up the more you scroll down.

Not sure if that's what you had in mind, but I'd look at a solution like this. You might want to add some conditions in there to ensure that top never goes below 0 or the nav will go off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, had a play around with both examples and they worked pretty good.

In the end I tweaked my code and instead of making the bar position top 0px I made it position top with the pixels equal to the offset distance. Don't know why I didn't think of this before.

On another note I am using Shinov's code for anoher project as I quite like it :)

Thanks

```
function banner(){

    var _barOffset = $('#top-bar').outerHeight(),
        _navOffset = $('#navigation').offset().top,
        _triggerOffset = _navOffset-_barOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var _scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (_scroll >= _triggerOffset) {
            $('#top-bar').css({'position':'absolute', 'top':_triggerOffset+'px'});
        }else if (_scroll <= _triggerOffset){
            $('#top-bar').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0px'});
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Also I'm sorry it took so long to get back to you both on this thread, had my internet disconnected all weekend.