# change margin-top on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, margin

i have a negative margin on a div, but I want to change the negative margin on scroll till the negative reaches 0.

*from:*

```
margin:-150px 0 0 0;
```

*to: (on scroll)*

```
margin:0px 0 0 0;
```

**i think it's some kind of parallax effect where i'm searching for and found this on StackOverflow:**
[Change margin top of div based on window scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481304/change-margin-top-of-div-based-on-window-scroll)

**i thought of something like this but there must be something easier**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1){ $('#three').css({margin:'-149px 0 0 0px'}); }
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 2){ $('#three').css({margin:'-148px 0 0 0px'}); }  
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 3){ $('#three').css({margin:'-147px 0 0 0px'}); }   
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 4){ $('#three').css({margin:'-146px 0 0 0px'}); }  
else { $('#three').css({margin:'-150px 0 0 0px'}); }
});
```

--

i created a fiddle with the html / css basis

**fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/

--

thank you so much in advanced

Comment: @FDL i only see my own fiddle, not your changed one :)

Comment: Sorry, updated it - http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/9/ or maybe http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/11/

Comment: @FDL the first one did the trick, awesome! do you want to place it as an answer so I can make it the right answer? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a little bit of math to automatically generate all of the possibilities (similar to your attempt but with a single line instead of one for each possibility.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/9/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#three").css('margin', '-' + (100 - fromTop) + 'px 0px 0px 0px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
$("#three").animate({margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}, 3000);
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/qSe4e/10/)

Comment: thankyou, its in that direction but i would like that if floats gently, i eddited my question with my own findings, maybe that tells the story a bit better

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren check the updated answer, if you want more slower, increase the time value

Comment: Rex, this one worked as well as the solution of FDL, the solution of FDL just fitted a bit more to what i was searching for but I want to thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren the main goal is to solve the  problem from any end :)

Comment: true! still i love your script and had a question; now the div only animates down when you scroll, is it also possible when you scroll up the div animates back to the minus margin?

Comment: i tried that but then it keeps on animating: http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/12/, I also tried with a javascript that tracks an upwards or downwards scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/13/